# How to autofit table rows to text box height after deleting a row in InDesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Is there a way to autofit an InDesign table to the size of the text box bounding frame by adjusting row height and/or column width? I am using the script below to delete empty rows from tables, but after deleting the row, the table no longer fills the space it is designed for.

Any suggestions or resources that may be helpful would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

```
var rows = app.activeDocument.textFrames.everyItem().tables.everyItem().rows.everyItem().getElements()
for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (rows[i].cells.everyItem().contents.toString().replace(/,/g, "") == "")
        rows[i].remove()
}

var columns = app.activeDocument.textFrames.everyItem().tables.everyItem().columns.everyItem().getElements()
for (var i = columns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (columns[i].cells.everyItem().contents.toString().replace(/,/g, "") == "")
        columns[i].remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple solution:

```
try { var cells = app.selection[0].cells } catch(e) { exit() }

app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, [], UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, 'Fit table')

function main() {

    // change the units to Points
    var old_h_units = app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits;
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.POINTS
    var old_v_units = app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits;
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.POINTS

    var first_cell = cells.firstItem().texts[0];
    var last_cell = cells.lastItem().texts[0];
    var id = first_cell.parentTextFrames[0].id;

    // change heights
    while (last_cell.parentTextFrames.length > 0
        && last_cell.parentTextFrames[0].id == id) {
        change_heights(cells, +.1);
    }
    change_heights(cells, -.1); // one step back

    // change widths
    var row = cells[0].parentRow;
    var borders = row.rightEdgeStrokeWeight/2 + row.leftEdgeStrokeWeight/2;
    var frame_width = get_width(first_cell.parentTextFrames[0]) - borders;
    while (cells[0].parentRow.width < frame_width) {
        change_widths(cells, +.1);
    }

    // restore the old units
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = old_h_units;
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = old_v_units;

}

// functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

function change_heights(cells, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) cells[i].height += value;
}

function change_widths(cells, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) cells[i].width += value;
}

function get_width(obj) {
    return obj.geometricBounds[3] - obj.geometricBounds[1];
}
```

Select the cells you want to resize and run the script. It increases height and width of the selected cells until the cells are fit in the parent text frame.

[image]

But it suggests to run the script manually for every problem table. If you mean to change all the tables in the document at once automatically there should be more complicated solution. Let me know if you need it. And it wouldn't hurt if you provide a sample of your document with the tables — there can be details that affect the algorithm.

---

**Update**

Here is the 'full-automatic' variant of the script:

```
app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, [], UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, 'Fit table')

function main() {

    // change the units to Points
    var old_h_units = app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits;
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.POINTS;
    var old_v_units = app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits;
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.POINTS;

    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var all_tables = [];

    // get all the tables
    var stories = doc.stories.everyItem().getElements();
    while(s = stories.pop()) {
        if (!s.textContainers[0].itemLayer.visible) continue; // exclude stories on hidden layers
        var tables = s.tables.everyItem().getElements();
        while(t = tables.pop()) all_tables.push(t);
    }

    // resize cells of all tables
    while (t = all_tables.pop()) resize_cells(t.cells);

    // restore the old units
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = old_h_units;
    app.activeDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = old_v_units;

}

// functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

function resize_cells(cells) {
    var first_cell = cells.firstItem().texts[0];
    var last_cell = cells.lastItem().texts[0];
    var id = first_cell.parentTextFrames[0].id;

    // chahge heights
    while (last_cell.parentTextFrames.length
        && last_cell.parentTextFrames[0].id === id) {
        change_heights(cells, +.1);
    }
    change_heights(cells, -.1); // one step back

    // change widths
    var row = cells[0].parentRow;
    var borders = row.rightEdgeStrokeWeight/2 + row.leftEdgeStrokeWeight/2;
    var frame_width = get_width(first_cell.parentTextFrames[0]) - borders;
    while (cells[0].parentRow.width < frame_width) {
        change_widths(cells, +.1);
    }
}

function change_heights(cells, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) cells[i].height += value;
}

function change_widths(cells, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) cells[i].width += value;
}

function get_width(obj) {
    return obj.geometricBounds[3] - obj.geometricBounds[1];
}
```

It gets all the tables of current document (except hidden layers), select all cells of each table and resize the cells to fit them in their parent text frame.

Not sure, is it okay to change highs of first and second row? Let me know if you don't want change highs of the first two rows.

Comment: Hi Yuri ! Thank you for responding again! I tried to use your script and it doesn't appear to work when I had a table or cells selected. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I found another script that appears to be working for adjusting the width, but doesn't work for height. Do you still have the same email? I can send you the test files and the script. Ideally, I would be able to run the script after running a data merge and deleting empty rows and columns. So yes, it would be great to run it automatically.

Comment: Hi, Steven! I got your email. I'll see what I can do and answer you.

Comment: In your case, the problem was in the measurement units. It's need to use Points for vertical and horizontal rulers. I've fixed the script, now it toggles all the units correctly. As for the automatic mode, it'll try to figure out the solution. But I'm afraid it won't be an universal solution. It will work fine for your specific layout only.

Comment: Hi Yuri! Thank you for helping out with this! I tried your updated code and it works perfectly for the manual selection. I am using the code in the original question to search every table for empty columns or rows, would you be able to use a snipet of that code to create a loop within the document? Or is the autofit code too complex? It's certainly too complex for my beginner mind to rap around how to integrate it, but this line seems like it would be useful in searching through each element: var rows = app.activeDocument.textFrames.everyItem().tables.everyItem().rows.everyItem().getElements()

Comment: I just added the full-automatic variant of the script. Try it.